# What is the power consumption of my LG refrigerator?

Tags: electrical

Can you help me find out what is my lg fridge wattage from the attached pictures? These are pictures for all the stickers on my fridge. Unfortunately I cannot find the manual.

The reason i am asking is that I want to connect it to my voltage transformer, because the house I live in now has only 220 volts, while the fridge and the microwave oven are 110. I have a transformer that powers up to 1500 VA. Please advise.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You did not tell your location but if you are in an area of 220 VAC voltages there is a good chance that you are also being supplied via a 50Hz service. The transformer will not perform 50 to 60 Hz conversion. Your refrigerator specs show that the unit requires 60 Hz.

Answer (score 4):

The nameplate wattage is volts X amps, or 127V X 2.4A = 305 watts. That's what the fridge will draw when the compressor is running. The compressor only runs periodically (ballpark 25% of the time, depending on the model), so the long-term average will be quite lower.

However you should also be aware that all motors, including the one in a fridge compressor, draw *significantly* power power during the first few seconds of operation. Could easily be 3 times as high. So if you are going to be running this from an inverter, make sure it is capable of around 1000 watts. Sometimes inverters have two ratings, a "surge" rating and a "continuous" rating, for exactly this reason. However the exact definition of a "surge" rating on an inverter is ambiguous, and some of them are only capable of running at their surge value for a fraction of a second, which may not be long enough to get the fridge started.

You haven't posted many specifics about the inverter or microwave, but running both appliances from that inverter may be pushing it, especially if the fridge compressor comes on when the microwave is going. Microwaves can draw 1000–2000 watts or more. (The "wattage" rating of a microwave is the energy that the food gets... actual consumption will be higher because of energy loss, electronics, motors, lights, etc.)

Comment: Edit restrictions prevent me from changing "power power" to "more power"